# Node.js best way to store variable to be used between multiple modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following Node.js app structure:
- `main.js` - main file 
- `./requests/requestSetName.js` - different functions sending different requests to API, so I have e.g. `userRequests.js`, `vechicleRequests.js` etc.

First thing I do in `main.js` is I send a request with login credentials to get access token. For all other requests I need to put this token in the request header. So each function in all modules in request folder needs to have access to it.

What is the best way to store this token and to be able to use it across different modules in `Node.js` ?

Comment: Pass it along to your module's functions as needed. Globals in Node.js (and programming in general) is frowned upon. If each function needs to have this  token, pass it to the function as a parameter when you call it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use classes for each request file and inject another class (Globals) witch contains the token , in the constructor of each request class, typescript should make It clean.